# Javascript double arrow functions

Tags: javascript, arrow-functions

This function is a click handler.

`const select = num => () => value += num;`

It has 2 arrows !!

1. Why? Could you use:
   `const select = (num) => value += num;`

if not, why not.

2. How would
   `const select = num => () => value += num;` ?
   look as a regular function

Comment: It's a function that returns a function, technically it's probably a click handler _factory_, with the function it returns being the click handler.

Comment: Also called high order function

Comment: If it is a click handler, then it is likely added like `.addEventListener('click', select(5))`, where the `select` function is invoked _immediately_  and the returned function `() => value += num` becomes the actual event handler.

Comment: It should probably be `const select = num => value => value += num;`

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković `+=` on a parameter that isn't used anywhere else doesn't make much sense. I expect that `value` is part of the lexical scope.

Comment: @Ivar You're right, I thought it was `value + num`

Comment: After some research:
'code' const select = num => () => value += num;
as a regular function looks like this
 const select = function(num) {
  return function() {
   value += num;
  };
 }